# How to get application permission settings in android and display in screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am developing a small application which lists permission settings of each application like this

[image: application's permission]

Can anyone help me how to check the permission and display like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the screen which you usually gets for a particular app in the settings. You cannot show the screen as it is. But you can make a toggle buttons group in your main activity and compare it with the current permissions.

You can follow this concept of Runtime app permissions to change the toggle and display on the screen.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Based on the boolean value you can target the particular permission toggle button and show as you want.